# Simple non-abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a simple non-abelian subgroup of $G$ which is ascendant in $G$. Is it true that $H$ is also subnormal in $G$?

**Definition**
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then we say that $H$ is ascendant in $G$ if we can find an ascendant (also of infinite length) normal series (not necessarily an invariant one) from $H$ to $G$.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "ascendant"?

Comment: I've specified that in the question now. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Yes much better now.

Comment: I can see no difference between the definitions of subnormal and ascendant. For subnormality the series has to be finite. Is the same true for ascendant?

Comment: Yes, for ascendant the series can also be infinite. Is not correct saying "ascendant" to meant also of infinite length?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know enough about posssible outer automorphism groups of infinite simple groups to be able to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Not true: take $H=A_5 \lt A_6 \lt G=A_7$. $A_5$ is not subnormal in $A_7$, since $A_7$ is simple.

Comment: Oh sorry maybe I used a wrong term. 
I meant "normal" as "normal in $G$". I know that someone used the term invariant for this. I've corrected the question. I hope now is really clear.

Comment: OK! But now I am totally confused. If there is an ascending normal series then automatically $H$ is subnormal in $G$.

Comment: Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascendant_subgroup): The series may be infinite. If the series is finite, then the subgroup is subnormal. 

I hope this will "deconfues" you.